# How do I associate org-mode source buffer to appropriate session?

Tags: org-babel

I want to execute org-babel code blocks associated with a session without locking up Emacs. I found the `ob-async` package, but it doesn't have support for sessions yet. I've found that opening the code block in a source buffer allows me to run code blocks without locking up Emacs. I'm mostly happy with that workflow. I can hit `C-' C-b` to evaluate R code blocks using ESS, for example.

One annoyance however is that I have to choose the instance to use for execution, if I have multiple R sessions open. This is particularly cumbersome, since I have to do this every time I revisit the code block using `C-'`. I'd like to have the session automatically associated (using the `:session` argument in the header). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the solution is:

```
(defvar tmprs nil)
(defun get-org-current-rsession()
  "When you are in an org file get the current R session based on global header, subtree, property or source code :session property whichever is relevant"
  (setq tmprs (cdr (assoc :session (nth 2 (org-babel-get-src-block-info t)))))
  )

(defun set-ess-R-process()
  "set the process to session stored in tmprs variable"
  (message "Setting R session to %s" (eval tmprs))
  (setq ess-local-process-name (process-name (get-buffer-process tmprs)))
  )


(advice-add 'org-edit-src-code :before #'get-org-current-rsession)
(advice-add 'org-edit-src-code :after #'set-ess-R-process)
```

see https://www.fredgruber.org/post/ess_emacs_default_r_session/ for more details